# CSS selectors select an element if a child element does not have a specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some HTML code that has this structure:

```
<div class="aclass">
<div class="bclass">
Content
</div>
</div>
<div class="aclass">
<div class="cclass">
Content
</div>
</div>
```

I only want to style all `div.aclass` provided there is not a child `div.bclass`. I have tried `div.aclass:not(* > div.bclass)` and `div.aclass:not(:scope > div.bclass)` and even `div.aclass:not(div.bclass)`, but none of them do it. Also the child does not need to be `cclass`, it can be any class, or even have no classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `div.aclass:not(:has(div.bclass))` if it does not matter for it to be a direct child. If it does matter, you can use `div.aclass:not(:has(> div.bclass))`.

Comment: Won't run in Firefox. https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin it should get approved within a few months, since even notorious Safari has had this implemented by default for half a year

Comment: Perhaps. But it's important to let people know about browser support when it's not complete across major browsers.